# How Can i Call method inside of onPostExecute()?

Tags: android

I want to Pass the Values to HTTP POST and get some Results, But I get small Problem while getting results from server.Everything in Same file

my Asycn Task

```
 private class GetCustomerDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
            try {
                return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
            }
        }

        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            parseData(result);// i am going to call method here
        }
    }

private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;
        // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
        // web page content.
        int len = 500;

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cus_name", cus_names));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("created_date1", createddate));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("created_date2", created_date));

        //String urlParameters ="cus_name=" + URLEncoder.encode(cus_names, "UTF-8") + "&created_date1=" + URLEncoder.encode(createddate, "UTF-8") + "&created_date2=" + URLEncoder.encode(created_date, "UTF-8");

        String urlParameters = URLEncoder.encode("cus_name", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(cus_names, "UTF-8");
        urlParameters += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("created_date1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(createddate, "UTF-8");
        urlParameters += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("created_date2", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(created_date, "UTF-8");

        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            //Create connection
            url = new URL(myurl);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            //Send request
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(getQuery(params));
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            //Get Response
            is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            System.out.println(response);
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            return response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        } finally {

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }

    }


    private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (NameValuePair pair : params) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
```

If its Right or wrong because my App get Stopped unfortunately. I think this is Correct way(May be).

my ParseData method

```
public void parseData(String result) {
    try {
        JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray data = parentObject.getJSONArray("sales_customer_repo");

        //JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url,params));
        ArrayList<CustomerData> customerArrayList = new ArrayList<CustomerData>();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
            String S_No = c.getString("S_No");
            String createdDate = c.getString("created_date");
            String orderNo = c.getString("order_no");
            String goods_name = c.getString("goods_name");
            String supply_qty = c.getString("supply_qty");
            customerArrayList.add(new CustomerData(S_No, createdDate, orderNo, goods_name, supply_qty));
        }
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, customerArrayList);
        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_customername);
        listView1.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        registerForContextMenu(listView1);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

While Debug my app this line to reach get my App Crashed

JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray data = parentObject.getJSONArray("sales_customer_repo");

LogCat:

```
07-04 15:43:59.775 12998-12998/com.example.vari.new_varri E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.vari.new_varri, PID: 12998
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                                at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
                                                                                at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
                                                                                at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
                                                                                at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
                                                                                at com.example.vari.new_varri.Sales_Customers_wise.parseData(Sales_Customers_wise.java:311)
                                                                                at com.example.vari.new_varri.Sales_Customers_wise$GetCustomerDataTask.onPostExecute(Sales_Customers_wise.java:191)
                                                                                at com.example.vari.new_varri.Sales_Customers_wise$GetCustomerDataTask.onPostExecute(Sales_Customers_wise.java:176)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: which error log print when app creshed

Comment: Looks like either the string isn't a well formatted jsonstring or it can't resolve "sales_customer_repo" key. Post log plz

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference @DivyeshBoda

Comment: I check my json format well @Memme

Comment: From the error you get, JSONArray data = parentObject.getJSONArray("sales_customer_repo"); can't find anything. So it's null and you can't do length. Post your json plz.

Comment: How to get JSON Plz @Memme

Comment: Print String result to console mate or toString(4) on parentObject

Comment: Thanks and I am getting NULL bro @Memme

Comment: Ok getting closer to the problem. Null on String result or on parentObject.toString? Would be nice if you posted LogCat error anyway

Comment: Yes I Post my  Logcat@Memme

Comment: downloadUri is returning a nulla object it seems. Have you tried printing out response.toString()?

Comment: my code can Run after this line wr.close(); it move to catch block @Memme

Comment: Ok, so there's the error. What's the stacktrace of the catch there?

Comment: By the way you are not closing the outputstream: //Send request
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    connection.getOutputStream()); change to os = connection.getOutputStream and pass it into the dataos, after wr.close add os.close

Comment: can you plz explain detail , why?@Memme

Comment: same problem bro @Memme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me, check that u use a correct url with protocol (http://www.ursite.com):

```
private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Starting");

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cus_name", cus_names));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("created_date1", createddate));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("created_date2", created_date));

        InputStream is = null;

        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            //Create connection
            url = new URL(myurl);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            //Send request
            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(os);
            wr.writeBytes("try=this");//replace with your getQuery
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            os.close();
            //Get Response
            is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();

            System.out.println(response);
            return response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        } finally {

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: No bro same error here . . .JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(response); its okay thank you

Comment: Can you pm me the url you are requesting? The snippet above is working for me, I'd like to check the response from your server.

Comment: its working in your system. i dont know what i make mistake. I am using local server,

Comment: actually i declare my URL in url variable, private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException (i change my parameter also url) not success

Comment: Ok I see. Try this url "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1" and check if you get a response (comment out the code in parseData after JsonObject parentObject. If it works it's a problem on the local server. PS: add protocol http::// before the address

Comment: did you mean replace my local url with this url right ? what happen when i use this url bro?

Comment: nope same problem bro so sad. no problem in my server its good bro . something else bro

Comment: Sorry couldn't help you more mate

Comment: its okay bro but I WILL DO IT , Thanks LOTTTTT bro